# How do I handle glm model objects saved within dataframe columns?

Tags: r, glm

I have a dataset, 'demographic_data', consisting of columns: count, city, sex, age, year. I'm using variables 'age' and 'year' to predict 'count' for each 'city'/'sex' combination. I've therefore produced a gam model for each combination by nesting the relevant data for use before building the models. This method is very useful for building multiple models for grouped data, however it results in the resulting gam objects being saved in columns.

My question is how can I use performance-checking functions on each gam object whilst they are saved in columns?

Here's a simplified example of the performance-checking function working on a gam object that isn't saved in a dataframe column:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(mgcv)

# select one group/combination of data
demo <- demographic_data  %>%
    filter(city == 'London',
           sex == 'Male')

# create gam object
gam_london_male <- gam(count ~ s(age) + s(year),
                       data = demo,
                       family = poisson,
                       method = "REML")

# performance-checking function on gam object
gam.check(gam_london_male) #this works and is very helpful
```

The function in the last line above works and is what I want to use for all models produced in my full dataset example below. Please can someone show me how to use gam.check() to produce a summary of each gam in the 'fit' column? My plan is to loop over each city/sex combination and run a function on each gam object in the 'fit' column but nothing I try works. Here's my code on the full dataset with groups so far:

```
# create models in 'fit' column for each city/sex combination
fitted_gam <- demographic_data  %>%
    nest(data = c(age,
                  year,
                  count)) %>%
    mutate(fit = gam(count ~ s(age) + s(year),
                     data = data,
                     family = poisson,
                     method = "REML")

# failed attempts to get gam.check() working on one group before adding city/sex combinations loop
test <- fitted_gam %>% filter(city == 'London', sex == 'Male') %>% select(fit)

gam.check(test)        #error: 'object is not a glm or gam'
gam.check(test$fit)    #error: 'object is not a glm or gam'
```

I haven't been able to find similar examples on this website or google. Any thoughts would be much appreciated! I'd like to keep the general method as above and be able to manipulate this fit column ideally if possible... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `nest`, we may use `map` to loop over

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(mgcv)
fitted_gam <- demographic_data  %>%
    nest(data = c(age,
                  year,
                  count)) %>%
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~ gam(count ~ s(age) + s(year),
                     data = .x,
                     family = poisson,
                     method = "REML"))
```

The `fit` is a list column, so we can loop over the `list` and apply the `gam.check

```
map(fitted_gam$fit, gam.check)
```

---

Or may also use `nest_by`

```
fitted_gam <-demographic_data %>%
     nest_by(city, sex) %>%
     mutate(fit = list(gam(count ~ s(age) + s(year),
                     data = data,
                     family = poisson,
                     method = "REML"))) %>%
     ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks for reading. Your comment looks like a good method to produce the models. Sorry my question was more how then can you use gam.check() on each of those models stored in the 'fit' column? I've got the function to work on a standalone gam but not when they're contained in a dataframe column.

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis after    `mutate(fit = map(data, ~ gam(count ~ s(age) + s(year),
                     data = .x,
                     family = poisson,
                     method = "REML"))`